# Call function in nodejs when an event occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working on a subnet scan with a backend(a.js) and a frontend(b.js).
The problem here is that the variable data is availiable in a.js but i need it in b.js. I think it would be the best if i write a function in b.js which is called when the scanner in a.js finds something. But i dont know how this is possible in Nodejs.

```
---a.js---
exports.scan = function() {
  scanSubnet();
  var data = [ip, port,...];
  //when the scanner finds something it is stored in the variable data
  //now the data should be availiable in b.js
}

---b.js---
var sc = require('./a.js');
sc.scan();
//i need a function here which is called when the scanner finds something
//so i can work with the variable data
```

Comment: can you modify `scan` to be an event emitter or take a callback?

Comment: Yes i think that would be a good idea with the callback.

Comment: Is b.js running in the browser, or also on the server?

Comment: It runs also on the server. The files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your scan function in a.js to accept callback and call it with the data.

```
---a.js---
exports.scan = function(callback) {
  scanSubnet();
  var data = [ip, port,...];
   callback(data);
}

---b.js---
var sc = require('./a.js');
sc.scan(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only going to be one function you need to call when the scanner finds something, then you can just use a setup function in the b.js module to register a callback function.

```
---b.js---
var scannerCallback;
module.exports.setScannerCallback = function(cb) {
    scannerCallback = cb;
}

var sc = require('./a.js');
sc.scan();
//i need a function here which is called when the scanner finds something
//so i can work with the variable data
if (scannerCallback) {
    scannerCallback(pass scanner data here)
}
```

If you may have more than one listener to the scanner data, then you may want to use an eventEmitter and emit an event with scanner data attached so that any listeners can see the new scanner data.

Comment: Thats what i mean and how can i call that in my a.js code?

Comment: @RaaZor188 - Sorry, but I don't understand what else you want to know.  Please explain more about what you're trying to do or what else you want help with.